# How do I extract certain words with a specific key letters inside a file with python

Tags: python, extract, genetic-algorithm

Sorry, im fairly new to python, never been trained much.

I want to ask how do I extract words with certain key letters inside of a file './models/asm/Draft_km.modelspec' in python for example (these lines can be found inside of the .modelspec file):

```
m_BSORx_kcat : 10
m_ENTERH_kcat : 10
m_TRPTRS_kcat : 10
m_EX_remnant1_e_kcat : 10
m_SCYSSL_kcat : 10
m_RNMK_kcat : 10
m_TAGtex_kcat : 10
m_URIDK2r_kcat : 10
m_TRPt2rpp_kcat : 10
m_GLUSy_kcat : 10
m_VPAMTr_copy2_kcat : 10
m_EX_galctn__L_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_galt_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_dgmp_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_galur_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_gam_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_gam6p_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_gbbtn_e_km : 0.001
```

I want to extract these inside a large '.modelspec' file by filtering "_kcat : 10"
and be able to obtain them as  `m_BSORx_kcat : 10, m_ENTERH_kcat : 10, m_TRPTRS_kcat : 10, m_EX_remnant1_e_kcat : 10, m_SCYSSL_kcat : 10, m_RNMK_kcat : 10, m_TAGtex_kcat : 10, m_URIDK2r_kcat : 10, m_TRPt2rpp_kcat : 10, m_GLUSy_kcat : 10, m_VPAMTr_copy2_kcat : 10`

My end goal is to be able to randomly reassign 10% of the value (-1,1) to do a genetic algorithm

Much help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Since you seem to be planning to modify the data, it might be useful to first split the lines into a list and then process each line individually.

```py
with open("./models/asm/Draft_km.modelspec") as f:
    # read lines, skipping empty lines and remove trailing whitespace
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in f if line.strip()]
```

If all you need to do is check for a substring, you can check each line like so:

```py
for line in lines:
    if "_kcat : 10" in line:
        print(line) # or do whatever you want
```

If you need to match more complex patterns, regular expressions as in Tim Biegeleisen's answer are the way to go.

Comment: Well, I'm planning to randomly reassign 10% of the value to produce 30 different results, still have not managed to figure out how am I going to do it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the next step would be to split each line at colon (`key, value = line.split(":")`) to get the key and the value, then cast the value into an integer so you can randomly modify it. But the details are really out of scope for this post.

Comment: yea something like that, guess i will ask in another post

Answer (score 0):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
# use this to read all lines into a string
with open('./models/asm/Draft_km.modelspec', 'r') as file:
    inp = file.read()

# otherwise we can hard code the data you showed in your question here
inp = """m_BSORx_kcat : 10
m_ENTERH_kcat : 10
m_TRPTRS_kcat : 10
m_EX_remnant1_e_kcat : 10
m_SCYSSL_kcat : 10
m_RNMK_kcat : 10
m_TAGtex_kcat : 10
m_URIDK2r_kcat : 10
m_TRPt2rpp_kcat : 10
m_GLUSy_kcat : 10
m_VPAMTr_copy2_kcat : 10
m_EX_galctn__L_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_galt_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_dgmp_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_galur_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_gam_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_gam6p_e_km : 0.001
m_EX_gbbtn_e_km : 0.001"""

matches = re.findall(r'\b\w+_kcat : \d+(?:\.\d+)?', inp)
output = ', '.join(matches)
print(output)
```

This prints:

> m_BSORx_kcat : 10, m_ENTERH_kcat : 10, m_TRPTRS_kcat : 10, m_EX_remnant1_e_kcat : 10, m_SCYSSL_kcat : 10, m_RNMK_kcat : 10, m_TAGtex_kcat : 10, m_URIDK2r_kcat : 10, m_TRPt2rpp_kcat : 10, m_GLUSy_kcat : 10, m_VPAMTr_copy2_kcat : 10

Comment: Typically we don't show imports in Python answers on this site if it would be obvious to anyone with Python experience which library is being used.  Yes, to make my answer work we need `import re` at the top of the script.

Comment: what if the list of data is inside a file in a folder? is it possible to put something like  `inp = ('./models/asm/Draft_KM.modelspec')`

Comment: @JohnSmith ... then you didn't ask the right question I guess.  Maybe you should edit and rewrite your question to the correct one.

Comment: Well, I perfectly understand your code, but not necessarily the person who asked the question. It solves the problem, but not very educational.

Comment: @Imago I can see that you are very new to the site.  SO is not a tutorial site, and there are plenty of those around.  It is a Q&A site.  Full explanations on regex from the ground up are way too broad for most questions and answers.

Comment: @JohnSmith Check the edit for a way to read your input file into a string.